# OpenCV linemod not cv member

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, ros

I try to install a `ROS indigo` package [jsk_recognition](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_recognition) for chessboard detection and relative position, I have `opencv-3.0.0-rc1` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. When I try to `catkin_make` the package I receive build errors, quit a lot, the full report is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GiIad1V6PYTrwBwH2t0HNTt1TVXWVdykfjaVYsM3VHg/edit?usp=sharing), but it starts like:

```
 [ 73%] Building CXX object
 vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/CMakeFiles/roi_to_mask_image.dir/roi_to_mask_image.cpp.o
 /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/src/linemod.cpp:69:57:
 error: ‘linemod’ is not a member of ‘cv’  std::vector<CvPoint>
 maskFromTemplate(const std::vector<cv::linemod::Template>& templates,
                                                          ^ /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/src/linemod.cpp:69:57:
 error: ‘linemod’ is not a member of ‘cv’
 /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/src/linemod.cpp:69:78:
 error: template argument 1 is invalid  std::vector<CvPoint>
 maskFromTemplate(const std::vector<cv::linemod::Template>& templates,
                                                                               ^
 /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/src/linemod.cpp:69:78:
 error: template argument 2 is invalid
 /home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_perception/src/linemod.cpp:69:57:
 error: ‘linemod’ is not a member of ‘cv’  std::vector<CvPoint>
 maskFromTemplate(const std::vector<cv::linemod::Template>& templates,
```

the problem seams to be with the `linemod` class, which in the online opencv documentation exist but in my case the compiler does not recognise it. The `linemod.h` header file can't be find in any opencv folder only in:

```
./home/elod/catkin_ws/src/vision/jsk_recognition-master/jsk_pcl_ros/include/jsk_pcl_ros/linemod.h
./opt/ros/indigo/include/jsk_pcl_ros/linemod.h
./usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/recognition/linemod.h
```

Is this module missing somhow my OpenCV installation or why cant find it in the cv namespace?

In my old `Opencv 2.4.11` (uninstalled) seams to be included this module, but I migrated all my stuff to `3.0.0`.

Any ideas how to solve it?

**UPDATE**
A very important observation is that the above mentioned pkg is for Opencv2.4 and I'm using 3.0! Some stuff was moved or removed from the new version like `cvSnakeImage`, which also appears in this pkg.

An other question would be: how to replace the `cvSnakeImage` or with what can be replaced?

Comment: I recently had a similar problem with `cv::line` and `cv::circle`. Maybe some functions have been moved to submodules in 3.0? (I did not find anything about it in the documentation, though)

Comment: In Opnecv3.0.0 the `cv::line` is the `c++` syntax so you need to include the `*.hpp` (see imgproc.*) headers or you can use the `cvLine` which is the `c` syntax with `*.h`. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build from scratch (clean build directory) ?

You could try adding cv:: namespace into *.hpp

```
-<linemod::Match>
+<cv::linemod::Match>
```

And/or try adding "`#include <opencv2/rgbd/linemod.hpp>`" into the same file.